# Geth networking error

Tags: go-ethereum, network

I ran Geth today for the first time. While it was running, I researched how to use fast mode. It turned out that I would have to restart it. 
So I closed the terminal and restarted Geth in a new instance of the terminal with the fast option enable. 
Now however, I get this error each time I try:

INFO [09-25|18:11:00] Starting P2P networking 
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen udp :30303: bind: address already in use

Comment: did you try to start with a different ort using the otpion `--port <port number>`. Eg. `-- port 30304`

Comment: Can you run `ps aux` in a terminal window and see if you have any other instances of `geth` running? Also, you might need to wait a bit for the port to free up if not bound with `SO_REUSEADDR` (although I would expect `geth` to use that). You can also run `lsof -i` to see what program has the port open. A reboot should work in the worst case.